# Нужна ли запятая в конкретном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Внешне ничем не примечательная девушка, но любимая и балуемая найдет свое счастье.*

Меня интересует пунктуация именно при таком построении предложения. Нужна ли запятая после слова *балуемая*?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая после "балуемая" **нужна**. Из Лопатина:

> Нераспространенные определения обособляются, если стоят после
>   определяемого имени существительного, **которое уже имеет определение**,
>   т. е. относятся к словосочетанию: *Первая моя московская осень, теплая
>   и приветливая, стояла долго*

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=132#pg132

То же у Розенталя:

> 6. Обособляются два или более одиночных (нераспространенных) определения, стоящих после существительного, если последнему
>      **предшествует еще одно** (или несколько) **определение**.
>      *Любимые лица, мёртвые и живые, приходят на память*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

При наличии уступительного значения обособление одиночному определению требуется и при отсутствии предшествующего определения при существительном:

> 3. Если определение, независимо от места в предложении, имеет добавочное обстоятельственное значение (причинное, условное,
>      **уступительное**):

https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-00000000b643c559a88a5950364e4e75

Comment: А где же  ваших примерах сочинительный союз НО? Бессоюзная связь - это совсем другая тема.

Comment: @Jasmin Ситуация нестандартная. Но Ваши аргументы (об однородных членах) тоже "хромают". Я думаю, должно ясно прослеживаться "девушка найдет свое счастье", одна запятая вносит путаницу (кто найдет свое счастье: "девушка" или "любимая и балуемая"?).

Answer (score 1):

**В ответ внесены изменения.**

**Внешне ничем не примечательная девушка, но любимая и балуемая найдет свое счастье.**

**Предложение действительно нестандартное,** в нем использована **инверсия,** сравнить: Девушка **внешне ничем не примечательная, но любимая и балуемая** найдет свое счастье.

Тем не менее я не вижу здесь причин для обособления, противительный союз НО относится к **однородным** определениям.

Но во втором варианте возможно обособление обоих определений: Девушка,  **внешне ничем не примечательная, но любимая и балуемая,** найдет свое счастье.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100

6. После последнего однородного члена предложения, присоединяемого противительным или подчинительным союзом и не заканчивающего собой предложения, **запятая не ставится** (т. е. последний однородный член не обособляется).